# Rails uploads for new object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, paperclip

When creating a new record (rails default new action), the object id is nil b/c it's unpersisted in the db.

When uploading objects, they're usually tied to an id (using paperclip).

When my user clicks on `new`, and I want to provide a dropzone.js area for ajax upload, how do I tie that image/file to the post object when it has no id?

If they discard or exit the browser, I would have orphaned temp images/files...

I'm having trouble connecting the dots between an object upload for a new record.

Can someone help me work out the controller logic for this?  I can do it pretty easily in a separate action after the object is created, but not before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a Gem to solve this kind of problem.
It works on top of paperclip and **is not intrusive**. To enable the functionality, you need to replace paperclip's `has_attached_file` with `has_attached_upload`.

Using [Rails Pallet](https://github.com/platanus/rails_pallet) gem...
First, you need to upload the file to your server performing `POST /uploads` with `file` attribute. The response will give you an **identifier** related to that file.
Then, sending the identifier, you can update your own record. The gem will copy the file to your record after that.

This way, you can upload files **before persisting** your record.

You can see a full example on gem's [README](https://github.com/platanus/rails_pallet/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Awesome. I'll look into it. Can you speak at all to refile as a paperclip replacement?

Comment: also is this rails 5 compatible?

Comment: It's a paperclip's complement, not a replacement. You replace `has_attached_file` by `has_attached_upload` only in the models you need. I didn't test it in Rails 5, Rails 4.2 only.

Comment: I just forked and changed gemspec for rails 5. Just got a `404` for `/uploads`. Do I need to add a post in routes.rb?

Comment: You need to run the installer `rails generate rails_pallet:install` to mount the gem and get the endpoint.

Comment: Yes, already generated. Using dropzone with POST to `/uploads' and `paramName: "file"`...should be all I need?

Comment: To create the file, yes. After that, you will see the identifier on response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109952/discussion-between-kevin-brown-and-leantraxxx).